# How does mysql_fetch_array() works

Tags: php, mysql

When I SELECT a column from table does `mysql_fetch_array()` returns the column values as an array?So that I can access the column values using array indexes?

I have this code

```
$s="SELECT col1 FROM tab1 WHERE course = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['course'])."'";
$result=mysql_query($s);
$num=mysql_num_rows($result);
$index=mysql_fetch_array($result);
echo $index[1];
```

I have two values in the col1 that satisfies this condition. But `echo $index[1];` doesn't display anything. If I type `echo count($index);` it gives `2`.

I want to select a column and access the column values one by one through a array indexes. How can I do this ?

Comment: Only one row per call is fetched, you can access it via `$index[0]` or `$index['col1']`. Please [read the manual](http://php.net/mysql_fetch_array) (and notice that big fat red box)

Comment: It doesn't - which is why we use mysqli_fetch_assoc (or PDO) instead

Comment: *"How does mysql_fetch_array() works"* - Please read the manual before posting http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
while($index=mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
   echo $index[0];// Or $index['col1'];
   echo "<br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Set second parameter to your `mysql_fetch_array()` that will ease you how you further access your result row i.e associative or numeric or both indices

```
 $s="SELECT col1 FROM tab1 WHERE course = '".mysql_real_escape_string($_SESSION['user']['course'])."'";
    $result=mysql_query($s);
    $num=mysql_num_rows($result);
    #$index=mysql_fetch_array($result);

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
       echo $row['col1'];// Or Set MYSQL_NUM then use like $row[0];  
       echo "<br>";
    }
```

**See**  http://php.net/mysql_query

> Warning This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be
>   removed in the future. Instead, the MySQLi or PDO_MySQL extension
>   should be used. See also MySQL: choosing an API guide and related FAQ
>   for more information. Alternatives to this function include:
>   mysqli_query() PDO::query()